# Prove that if $B$ is similar to $A$, then $B^T$ is similar to $A^T$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

If two matrix ($A$ and $B$) are similar if there exists an invertible matrix $P$, such that:
$$ B=P^{-1} A P $$
I'm thinking if I can prove that $A$, $B$ , $A^T$ and $B^T$ have the same characteristic polynomial then that would prove the above statement. However, I am a little unsure how to put the whole proof together.

Comment: Note: just because two matrices have the same characteristic polynomial, doesn't mean they're similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since

$B = P^{-1} A P, \tag{1}$

$B^T = P^T A^T (P^{-1})^T; \tag{2}$

Now

$PP^{-1} = I, \tag{3}$

whence

$(P^{-1})^T P^T = I \tag{4}$

as well; but (4) implies

$(P^{-1})^T = (P^T)^{-1}; \tag{5}$

thus (2) becomes

$B^T = P^T A^T (P^T)^{-1}, \tag{6}$

so $A^T$ is similar to $B^T$,

putting the whole proof together! ***QED.***

Answer (score 5):

If $B$ is similar to $A$, then we write $$B = P^{-1}AP$$ for some invertible $P$. Then transposing everything, we get: $$B^T = (P^{-1}AP)^T = P^TA^T(P^{-1})^T = P^TA^T(P^T)^{-1}.$$ Since $P$ is invertible, $P^T$ is also invertible. So $B^T$ is similar to $A^T$, and the matrix who plays the role of $P$ in the definition is $P^T$ now.

Comment: For the OP:  tucked into the calculation is the fact that $(P^T)^{-1} = (P^{-1})^T$, which should be justified.  It's a one-liner, as well.  Since $P^T (P^{-1})^T = (P^{-1}P)^T = I^T = I$, it must be that $(P^T)^{-1} = (P^{-1})^T$.

Comment: I'm unsure why the transpose of an invertible matrix is its inverse?
(That is, in you proof, the role of P and P inverse change positions.)

Comment: The transpose of an invertible matrix is not its inverse. The inverse of the transpose is the transpose of the inverse, that's different. I mean that you can swap $(P^{-1})^T = (P^T)^{-1}$, but Sammy Black justified this nicely in his comment. (Note that he used the uniqueness of inverses there)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose A is similiar to B so we will have $A = P^{-1}BP$
So $A^{T} = (P^{-1}BP)^{T} \rightarrow A^T = P^TB^T(P^{-1})^T$  so A transpose is similiar to B transpose.